# What are CUI.debug.js files and why are they needed?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

Our server has had some issues lately and we've been keeping our eye on the processes running.

One process taking up a lot of memory is using CUI.debug.js. I'm assuming it's used for debugging? What is this? Do we need it? How can I turn it off?

Thanks,
Ninel

Comment: Which Process? Is this on a web front end?

Comment: This is our intranet and it is on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: What did you use to say that it was using a lot of memory, and what specifically is using the js file?

Answer (score 3):

In the masterpage, look for the `ScriptManager` tag and set the `ScriptMode` attribute to `Release` to disable the loading of .debug.js files by the server to the clients.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode.aspx